# pandas groupby cummax just assigning original values instead of updating the max-so-far

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe:

```
    type      run   corrected_episode   Reward
0   notsweet    0   0                   35.0
1   notsweet    0   100                 20.0
2   notsweet    0   200                 20.0
3   notsweet    0   300                 22.0
4   notsweet    0   400                 20.0
```

I want to create a new column, `best_so_far`, that has a monotonically increasing value for the corresponding `Reward` grouped by `type`, `run`, and `corrected_episode`.  Easy enough, right?  Except the following happens when I try to use `groupby` and `cummax`:

`foo['best_so_far'] = foo.groupby(['type','run','corrected_episode']).Reward.cummax()` yields:

```
type            run corrected_episode   Reward  best_so_far
0   notsweet    0   0                   35.0    35.0
1   notsweet    0   100                 20.0    20.0
2   notsweet    0   200                 20.0    20.0
3   notsweet    0   300                 22.0    22.0
4   notsweet    0   400                 20.0    20.0
```

The "best so far", well, isn't the best.  I get the same results if I use `foo['best_so_far'] = foo.groupby(['type','run','corrected_episode']).Reward.apply(lambda x: x.cummax())`

I know this is possible because I've done this dozens of times with other dataframes, there's just something weird about this one that this simple procedure just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try remove `corrected_episode`

```
foo['best_so_far'] = foo.groupby(['type','run']).Reward.cummax()
```

Answer (score 0):

After posting this of course I discovered what happened, but I'm going to share what I did to fix this here because this is the kind of Violation of the Principle of Least Astonishment that pandas is prone to.

The solution was to do this, instead:

`foo['best_so_far'] = foo.groupby(['type','run']).Reward.cummax()`

That is, I over specified the columns by including `corrected_episode` that had the unintended effect of just executing `cummax()` *for that one element*.  However, I had originally included `corrected_episode` to ensure that *the order* of the rows was correct -- i.e., the dataframe was actually the result of massaging a lot of data (you are seeing a teeny tiny subset), and the order of the data wasn't necessarily sane for the `cummax()` to work as I envisioned.